# Am I allowed to stay in Turkey beyond the period of my tourist visa if I have applied for the residence permit online but am not yet interviewed?

Tags: tourist-visas, turkey, residency

I have been in Turkey for 2 months and 25 days on a 3 month tourist visa. I have applied online for the short term residence permit 3 days ago but am not yet appointed for an interview.

Can I stay in turkey beyond my visa period or should I exit and re-enter the country for the interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don’t have to leave the country. The [UK government travel advice for Turkey](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-turkey) states:

> If you plan to stay in Turkey longer than 90 days, you must apply for a residence permit before the 90 days ends or apply for a longer-stay visa before you travel

So as long as you apply for it before your visa expires you can stay in the country.